# How to load 1TB of data into MySQL efficiently?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 1TB worth of text data in several files. A 15GB file has around 700million rows, so I am estimating the total number of rows is nearing 100 billion. The data has the following structure:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| label1 | label2 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The labels are strings, the values are ints. In the files, everything is divided using tab characters, making for an easy import.

Ultimately, I need to be able to search for rows where either "label1" or "label2" equals a certain string. I thought MySQL would be the perfect solution. Given the size of the data, I am doubting the efficiency of MySQL though.

Using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" seems to be the recommended way of importing data into MySQL. Even after toying around with the import settings, the import seems to take too long. Some answers on StackOverflow suggest the import speeds range from 200-400million rows per hour.

Is there any other import method that would be much faster? I was hoping to import all of the data in under 6 hours.

Is MySQL even a good solution for this kind of a task?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place for software/service recommendations, so this is a comment.  You should be looking for a database that has better support for parallel queries, such as MariaDB or Postgres 9.6 (among the free databases).  If you are really concerned about speed, you might look into Cloud based solutions, such as BigQuery, RedShift, SQL Azure.  Those are commercial services and would tend to cost money.

Comment: There are so many questions here.  Do you plan to continually have a need to import so much data, or is this a one-off thing?  If the latter, then just watch Netflix until it finishes.  Also, what do you plan on doing with the data?

Comment: "A 15 Gbyte file has 700 million rows".  That is about 21 bytes per row.  With 1 character separator and assuming just one byte for end of record, you have 16 bytes in 5 columns, or 3 bytes per column.  My guess is either that your estimates are way off or the data is really, really repetitive.

Comment: I have a feeling that the question is not true. For a start why would you get into such a mess with "text" files with a row so small.

Comment: I appreciate the comments.
The question is definitely true, although perhaps flawed conceptually. I'm not familiar with datasets this big, which is why I am asking here.

The data is a processed version of the Google NGram corpus, which shows how often words appear together in books. Label1 and label 2 is a pairs of words, value 1 is year of appearance and values 2+3 are the number of times the words appear together.

The text files are generated by my C# code, mainly limited by IO speed. I could import from C# directly into MySQL, but I assume that's even slower.

Comment: what are the output need ? 1Tb of data sound like "distributed nosql" for me: putting them straight into a single table is **totally useless**, sql query will take hours to complete. you need partitioning and advanced DB tuning if you stick to relational DB... (or 50k$ and Oracle-exadata)